# iOS - HLS video no longer played in WebView after iOS 10.2 update

Tags: ios, iphone, webview, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

So I need to play HLS video inside a webview, everythings work well until recent 10.2 update (this also happens in 10.2.1). I display the video using standard `<video>` tag, and on some page I use JWPlayer to play the video too.

Currently this only occurs in iPhone 5 (10.2), everything works well in iPhone 5S, 6, 7, 7 Plus, iPad Pro and even iPhone 5 with old OS (9.3.2)

Anyone have any idea what's the cause of this?

Comment: I have the same issue on 10.2 iPads. HTML videos doesn't play.

Comment: @Devrim I solved my problem, check my answer! Hope it can solve yours too :)

Comment: Sounds great. However, I'm not an iOS developer but will pass this on to my team. Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me how did you manage to run it inside a webview? Any html5 code will be helpful.

Comment: same issue on iOS 10.3.1 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem with switching from UIWebView to WKWebView.
I guess like what apple wrote in their documentation we should switch to WKWebView for future support.

[reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wkwebview)

Comment: Thank you, but personally I don't recommend switching to WKWebView because of JWPlayer. Must be another solution.